# Is it possible to an make area with lower z-index clickable without JS or imagemap?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I've designed a website with an elaborate transparent header that has to pass over part of the main section of the page. I'm trying to keep the number of images used in the website down to a minimum, partly for size and partly for cleaner markup.

I want to start putting clickable items in a blank area under the transparency. I managed to get the image to overlap the div in question by playing with the z-index. Now of course, it's unclickable.

Does anyone have a clever solution to this problem? I can think of several different ways "around" the problem that are less ideal, but I'm hoping to avoid those and find a solution that doesn't use JS or an imagemap. I've tried to use a nested div with a higher z-order (outer div is -1, inner div is 1), but it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you post a sample/screenshot of intended output? It'd be a great help and some code that you have tried?

Comment: Yes, it seems odd that you first block something out and then want to make it clickable.. Only way i see you could click item that is blocked by another one.. is that if you temporeraly change it to be on top... But then again that doesnt really make sense..

Comment: Which browsers/versions do you need to support?

Comment: Well, the idea was that the content in the lower z-index is behind a part of the image that has 100% transparency, as I said earlier, so it isn't hidden. Nonetheless, I solved my own problem, as detailed below. Though I haven't tested it fully to make sure it behaves consistently cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it wasn't necessary at all to change the z-index. All I had to do was use the negative margin and I could click the content in the transparent area under the image. My mistake was making the initial assumption that I would need to change the z-index for some reason. If I had attempted it without touching the z-index, It wouldn't have been an issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can $.Event to make an event and then trigger it when ever needed :)
prefectly cross browser and easy